# Clustering issue with imbalanced data (K-means error analysis)

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, imbalanced-data

I am facing a clustering issue and I really hope anyone can help me.

After using t-SNE, which seems to be the most effective dim reduction technique for my data, I end up with a feature space of the shape (647,2).

When I visualize the feature space, I can clearly see that the data was separated into 4 distinct clusters. Indeed, 4 is the correct number of classes here. Classes are not in balance.

Class 1: 160 objects
Class 2: 396 objects
Class 3: 38 objects
Class 4: 53 objects

However, when I apply k-means clustering the algorithm decides to split cluster 2 into two clusters, and put clusters 1 and 3 together. This happens, from my POV, because they are located closely. However, since it is obvious to me that they are better to separate than class 2, I wonder if there is a better way to cluster the data.

I will attach a figure of the feature space, and how k-means clusters it.

t-sne feature space
[image]

k-means clustering results
[image]

I tried several other clustering methods, like GMM, or hierarchical clustering. This happens for all algorithms...